# CodenameOne InfiniteContainer Scrolling

Tags: codenameone

In the simulator it works perfectly well, but in a smartphone when scrolling down in the infinitecontainer we can see a black flickering (probably related to getting data from the server)

Can we somehow prevent this behaviour?

Thanks
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your code doesn't block the fetch method for too long. It needs to be very fast.

If you need networking to construct the components make sure you use `addToQueueAndWait` and process the components correctly on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I reviewed the code but it is a fast code. Its pratically codename one example. But still seeing the black flickering. And i´m using the addToQueueAndWait. But will give it another try.

Comment: Do you see it in the kitchen sink in the dogs demo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codename1.demos.kitchen ?

Comment: In that case it might be a bug what device are you using exactly with OS version etc? If you connect the device with a cable and DDMS do you see any printouts such as exceptions etc?

Comment: I´m testing it in a Samsung S3 - Android 4.4.2. I´m going to test it on other devices...

Comment: I'll try to grab an older device I have here to reproduce this although I don't think I have a 4.x device anymore. Do you see anything in DDMS?

Comment: Will try to do this... i´m a newbie at mobile and at CodenameOne - But loving the experience ;)

Comment: No need, I was able to reproduce the issue and I see it, we're looking into it.